# Understanding who's passing a parameter from the $.get function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use jQuery a lot for DOM manipulation, animations, and stuff, mostly front end, but even though I know jQuery is great for AJAX, I've never used it for that purpose. Now I saw the following interesting piece of code on [this site](http://code.octopuscreative.com/fancyselect/):

```
$.get('https://api.github.com/repos/octopuscreative/' + repoName, function(repo) {
        var el = $('#top').find('.repo');
        el.find('.stars').text(repo.watchers_count);
        el.find('.forks').text(repo.forks_count);
});
```

Now see how the parameter `repo` , is being used to display the number of stars and forks, that's really interesting. Now my question is, who is passing the `repo` parameter to the function to the function? How is this variable coming in from thin air?

Comment: The second parameter to the get() method is the `success callback function`, which is passed the returned data, which will be an XML root element, text string, JavaScript file, or JSON object, depending on the MIME type of the response. For more info, read https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in function i.e repo is the response of server for success. Hence it actually contains html/text content.
See specification:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/